# Any ORM that can work with tables without PK?

Tags: c#, orm

I'm building a Web App that has to interact with a database that has multiple tables without PK.

The database is designed intentionally like this and the schema sadly can't be modified.

I tried using Entity Framework but it has a lot of issues with this kind of tables. There seems to be a few ways to trick this, (lie to EF about the primary key i.e.), but it might introduce annoying bugs in the future.

After a quick research on NHibernate, it apparently has similar issues to EF.

I will be trying my luck with Dapper now, but perhaps any of you guys have an alternative or definitive solution for a project like this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dapper accepts raw SQL.  [So does Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx).  If you can solve your problem using raw SQL, you can make it work using either of these tools.  Executing the query and getting a result is a single function call.

Comment: When i try to map the database with EF DbFirst, the tool fails to map the tables without primary keys and all of their relations. The model is built with all kind of errors and warnings.

Any way to sort that out?

Thabks for your answer.

Comment: Dapper will work, for sure.

Comment: you can also map all the fields as a composite key. won't work if that's not unique.

Comment: @EmilianoRodriguez: That's because you're trying to use the code-generated entities that EF provides.  You'll need to write your own entity classes to map to, or return the result into a `dynamic` variable, and forget about EF's entities.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a primary key.  Just pick any unique index, and configure the ORM to use that index's columns as the key.

If there really are no unique indexes, then what are you planning to do with the data?

If there is really no subset of the tables columns that you can assume uniquely identify a row, then you'll never be able to update individual rows.  You can pretend that it has some key, and only query it.